# Operator which can be interpreted as binary and unary

Tags: symbolic, operators

I'm a bit lost with the way how e.g. the + operator is implemented in *Mathematica* as binary (infix) and unary (prefix) operator depending on the context, since I would like to define a similiar behaviour e.g. for the CirclePlus operator.

If one uses the $+$ operator as $+a$ then one gets the expected result $a$.

Since $+$ is by definition a Binary operator the expression $a+b$ is translated into $Plus[a,b]$.

Now how could I specify a similar behavior for e.g the $\oplus$ binary operator? Obviously $a \oplus b$ is translating nicely into CirclePlus[a,b] as expected.

However if I try $\oplus a$ I get a syntax error "$\oplus a$ is incomplete; more input is needed."

I'm sure I miss here some additional definition or rule necessary to get this behavior.

Comment: There could be something of use in the Notation package. I've never defined a unary operator, only binary infix, but [this looks helpful](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87/creating-custom-notation)

Comment: `Plus` has the `OneIdentity` attribute, that's why `Plus[a] = a`. Try setting that attribute for `CirclePlus`. Or more generally, just define what `CirclePlus[a]` should be, as it doesn't have any built-in meaning.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer: Both approaches are unfortunately not working. The error still persists.

Comment: Rainer, are you sure of that? Because if I set `CirclePlus[x_]=x` on my machine, then evaluate `CirclePlus[a]`, I obtain `a` as the output, which I thought is what you want.

Comment: Try this: MakeExpression[RowBox[{"\[CirclePlus]", x_}], StandardForm] := 
 MakeExpression[RowBox[{x}], StandardForm]

Comment: @jamtype7 that's it! If I use MakeExpression[RowBox[{"\[CirclePlus]", x_}], StandardForm] := MakeExpression[RowBox[{x}] (you forgot the backslash) then I get the intended behaviour that $\oplus a$ yields the expected result a.  Do you know if it is possible to see all MakeExpression definitions related to e.g. the + operator?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer: your code is just working when using CirclePlus[a] but not working with the $\oplus a$ syntax as described above.